# Error: Builder (android.content.Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (com.example.pc.chromecast.MainActivity.MediaRouterCallback)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having an error in this part of the code:

```
private void launchReceiver() {
        Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions
                .builder( mSelectedDevice, mCastClientListener );

        ConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks();
        ConnectionFailedListener mConnectionFailedListener = new ConnectionFailedListener();
        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi( Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build() )
                .addConnectionCallbacks( mConnectionCallbacks )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener( mConnectionFailedListener )
                .build();

        mApiClient.connect();
    }
```

This is the line where the error is:

```
mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
```

The error says:

```
Builder (android.content.Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (com.example.pc.chromecast.MainActivity.MediaRouterCallback)
```

What do I need to do to resolve the problem?